# Check whether a string contain '&' character only

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

How to check whether a string contains "&" only. I mean that if user will enter & or &&& or a string of '&'. Please note that http://myurl.com/&var=79 or something like this should be ignored. It should check for those string which contains & character. Please help me!!!

Comment: "or something like this" is too vague.

Comment: Please give an example of a string that would be rejected ("contains '&' only") , a string that would be ignored, and a string that would be accepted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way with regex but here is a possible solution:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char testChar = '&';
            string test1 = "&";
            string test2 = "&&&&&&&&&&";
            string test3 = "&&&&&&&u&&&&&&&";

            Console.WriteLine(checkIfOnly(testChar, test1)); // true
            Console.WriteLine(checkIfOnly(testChar, test2)); // true
            Console.WriteLine(checkIfOnly(testChar, test3)); // false
            Console.WriteLine(checkIfOnly('u', test3));      // false
            Console.WriteLine(checkIfOnly('u', "u"));      // true
            Console.WriteLine(checkIfOnly('u', "uuuu"));      // true


        }

        static bool checkIfOnly(char testChar, string s)
        {
            foreach (char c in s)
            {
                if (c != testChar) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 18):

when you say

> string contains "&" only

i assume, that a string with any other character is invalid.

```
string str = "&&&";
bool result = str.All(x => x == '&'); //true, because it contains no other char
```

---

another way  - oneliner without linq

```
bool result = str.Replace("&", String.Empty).Length == 0;
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a rather simple way to do it:

```
bool allAmpersands = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Trim('&').Length == 0;
```

If the string is not empty, it checks if there is anything left in the string after removing the ampersand characters at both ends.

Answer (score 5):

Solution with RegEx

```
string str = "&&&&"; 
bool b = Regex.IsMatch(str,"^&+$");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bool ContainsOnlyAmpersand(string str){ return str.?Length > 0 && !str.Any(c => c != '&'); }
```

Returns false for null/empty string.
This should be more performant than other answers because `Any()` can abort early, whereas `All()` must always fully evaluate a string.
The `Except('&')` approach creates an extra iterator, and is likely slower for that reason (though benchmarks would be needed to know for sure).

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, but assuming that the idea is to test whether the string is composed of only & characters, here is yet one more way to check:

```
bool containsOnlyAmps = false;
string testString = "&";

containsOnlyAmps = 
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(testString) 
    && testString == new string('&', testString.Length);
```

This works by first checking that we have a non-null, non-empty string. Then it uses the `string.String(char c, int count)` overload of the `string` constructor. It generates a string that contains the given char repeated count times. So we give in the character `&`, repeat it `testString.Lenght` times, then compare the result with `testString` itself.

If the original string has any other character, then `containsOnlyAmps` will be false. Otherwise true.

Answer (score 1):

What about using regex:

```
string strMatch = "Yeah& yeah yeah";
string strNoMatch = "Yeah &&yeah yeah";
Regex r = new Regex("^[^&]*&[^&]*");
r.IsMatch(strMatch);   // returns true
r.IsMatch(strNoMatch); // returns false
```

Regex breakdown:

```
^[^&]*  -- string beginning, match any number of occurrences of "not &"
&       -- match exactly one "&"
[^&]*   -- match the rest of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's late, hope this will help

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string url = "http://myurl.com/&&var=79";
        string[] parameters = url.Split('&');

        //Method 1 - just to check existance of "&" character
        if(parameters.Length > 0) Console.WriteLine("Character '&' present");

        //Method 2 - check if repeated occurence of "&" exists
        bool isRepetedExistance = false;
        foreach(string keyValuePair in parameters) {
            if(keyValuePair.Length == 0) {
                isRepetedExistance = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Repeted existance of character '&' is {0}present", (isRepetedExistance ? "" : "not ")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
string str;
Regex r = new Regex ("&");
bool b = r.IsMatch (str);
```

or use LINQ

```
new[] { "&" }.All(c => s.Contains(c))
```

or try this:

```
if (str.Except("&").Any())
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: RegEx is  true in case of `string str = "foo&";`

Comment: LINQ is true in case of `string str = "foo&";`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do it with regex. ^&+$ matches whole strings that only contain the character '&'. I suggest reading up on regex it might seem complicated but comes in handy when trying to parse or filter strings.

```
string invalid = "ccc&cc";
string valid = "&&";

if(Regex.IsMatch(invalid, "^&+$"))
    Console.WriteLine("Does not execute");

if(Regex.IsMatch(valid, "^&+$"))
    Console.WriteLine("Will execute");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way of checking if any string has an ampersand sign:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool ans = HasAmpersandSign("some&word");
        Console.WriteLine(ans);
    }

    private static bool HasAmpersandSign(string s)
    {
        return s.Contains("&");
    }
}
```

However, if you want to check that the string ONLY has ONE ampersand sign you are indirectly implying that the string needs to be only one character in length.

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "&someword";

            bool ans = HasAmpersandSign("some&word");

            Console.WriteLine(ans);

            Console.WriteLine(HasAmpersandSignOnly(s));
        }

        private static bool HasAmpersandSign(string s)
        {
            return s.Contains("&");
        }

        private static bool HasAmpersandSignOnly(string s)
        {
            return s.Contains("&") && s.Length == 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate/check that a string is containing only ampersand(the `&` sign) characters

You could the `Regex` class from `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Check the below code example. You can execute it [here](http://rextester.com/NBR86079)

```
string test1 = "&";
string test2 = "&&&&&&&&&&";
string test3 = "&&&&&&&u&&&&&&&";
var test4 = "foo&";
var regex = new Regex("^[&]+$");

Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(test1));
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(test2));
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(test3));
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(test4));
```

The regular expression `[&]+` checks for one or more occurances of the ampersand sign

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code

```
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateString("", '&')); //False
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateString("Foo&", '&')); //False
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateString("&Foo", '&')); //False
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateString("&&&", '&')); //True
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateString("&", '&')); //True
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

   static bool ValidateString(string str, char testChar) 
   {
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return false;
     if (Regex.Matches(str, testChar.ToString()).Count == str.Length)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
static readonly Regex Validator = new Regex(@"^[&]+$");

public static bool IsValid(string str) {
    return Validator.IsMatch(str);
}
```

The regex works like this:

```
^ matches the beginning of the string
[...] matches any of the characters that appear in the brackets
+ matches one or more characters that match the previous item
$ matches the end of the string
```

Without the ^ and $ anchors, the regex will match any string that contains at least one valid character, because a regex can match any substring of the string use pass it. The ^ and $ anchors force it to match the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

This will return true if the string contains anything other than ampersands.

The OP doesn't specify what to do if the string is empty - this code will return false in that case.

```
bool ContainsNonAmpersands=!Regex.IsMatch(str,"[^&]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you want to do this check I would make use of a `Regex` object to check the string. In general regular expressions are very useful when searching for patterns in text. Here **^** indicates the beginning of the string and **$** the end of the string/line.

```
Regex re = new Regex("^&+$");

re.IsMatch("&&&&&");          // returns true
re.IsMatch("www.url.com/&2"); // returns false
```

Answer (score -4):

```
  string s = "&&& &&&";

  if (s.Contains("&"))
  {
     //do your work
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything to ensure that the string will *only* contain `&` characters.